# Fpdf multi cell not auto breaking page

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I would like to write a paragraph that is not split across two pages.
If the cell contains more text than can fit on the page, I'd like it to print on a new page.

More precisely, I should build a quiz with multiple answers. If a question with his answers request more lines than can fit on the page, I'd like it to print entirely on a new page.

This is my python code:

```
for i in range(0, len(questions)):  # for every question
            pdf.ln(4)
            pdf.multi_cell(0, 4, questions[i], 1)
```

'questions' is a string array. Every item contains a text with many lines (a line with the question and four lines with the possible answers)

In the screenshot you can see question number 9 splitted in two pages. I would like it to print it automatically on the second page only.

[image: example]

Comment: In what way does this relate to PHP? You seem to be talking about python, but then tagged with php and fpdf. It doesn't seem linked. Please clarify the scenario. See also [ask] and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also please take the [tour], as you're new. Then you can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: "php" tag is mentioned because fpdf library exists for php too, not only for python

Comment: Ok. But if you're coding in python, then how is that relevant to the specific question? Don't just tag stuff because it's vaguely similar, tag it because it relates to **your** issue. Please read the guidance I provided (I see from the lack of badge in your profile that you haven't studied it all yet).

Comment: The problem of this topic is not strictly related to the programming language used. I am using python but also a user using the same library on php would be able to help me.

Comment: pypdf is a separate python port of fpdf and was split a while back. It has nothing to do with PHP from what I observe. There's no indications the versions are kept in sync, so an issue in one may or may not be an issue in the other. And no-one could help you by writing code in PHP, so the PHP code tag isn't relevant - that's only for use if the question and answer would involve PHP directly. You _could_  use the fpdf tag at a stretch, but I've retagged with the specific pyfpdf tag which is more directly relevant.